Missing upgrade of GRUB kernel boot list
For some reason GRUB will not update the list of available kernels after a routine update
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found initrd image: initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found initrd image: initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

This is the contents in the boot folder:
$> ls -lah /boot
total 185M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   15 Oct  2 14:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root   26 Apr 27 20:04 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 281K Oct  2 13:23 config-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 281K Aug 30 10:32 config-6.8.0-45-generic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    2 Sep 11 02:18 efi
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4 Oct  2 14:57 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Oct  2 14:50 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  77M Oct  2 13:48 initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  77M Oct  2 14:50 initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Oct  2 14:56 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 8,7M Aug 30 10:32 System.map-6.8.0-45-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Oct  2 14:50 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  15M Aug 13 12:22 vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  15M Aug 30 11:02 vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Oct  2 14:56 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic

I completely purged version 45 and reinstalled it. I cant see any errors and neither can apt.
When I reboot I will end up in emergency mode and I have to manually move back to the 44 version of the kernel via
update-initramfs -u -k 6.8.0-44-generic

Then the system boots as expected - but on the old kernel.
What is up with grub?
Bug reported to the grub-amd64-efi package
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-unsigned/+bug/2084584

"grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem."  Grub not recognizing rpool settings. Grub has drivers for non-standard configurations or its .mod files. Is this zfs and is it encrypted. Are those .mod files in grub's grub.cfg so correctly used?

This seems to be sourced by /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs and/or /etc/grub.d/10_linux both produce a cannot open /grub-mkconfig_lib: No such file. It seems to be an attempt at the following source . "${pkgdatadir}/grub-mkconfig_lib" - so if pkgdatadir is blank - this would result in the error produced by both the above and thusly - probably also by grub-mkconfig. I do not know what the correct fix would be though

Setting pkgdatadir="/usr/share/grub" in /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs and linux makes them produce an output - however it seems to still be ignored by grub-mkconfig and grub-update

I think I worked this out. You are able to execute an update-grub even if your pools are not correctly imported into zfs.
I noticed the list looked like this:
$> zpool list
NAME SIZE ALLOC FREE CKPOINT EXPANDSZ FRAG CAP DEDUP HEALTH ALTROOT
rpool 1.84T 141G 1.71T - - 1% 7% 1.00x ONLINE -

After an import of the bpool.
$> sudo zpool import bpool.

Now looks like
$> zpool list
NAME SIZE ALLOC FREE CKPOINT EXPANDSZ FRAG CAP DEDUP HEALTH ALTROOT
bpool 1.88G 285M 1.60G - - 0% 14% 1.00x ONLINE -
rpool 1.84T 141G 1.71T - - 1% 7% 1.00x ONLINE -

And the grub scripts once again starts behaving. A full reinstall of the latest *47 kernel now correctly updates the boot selection list and lets me boot into the correct kernel.
$> sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found initrd image: initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found initrd image: initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found initrd image: initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_9jipvg
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /BOOT/ubuntu_9jipvg@/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

To reflect
$> ls -lah /boot
total 279M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   23 Oct 15 22:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root   26 Apr 27 20:04 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 281K Aug  2 16:15 config-6.8.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 281K Aug 13 12:20 config-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 281K Oct 15 22:02 config-6.8.0-47-generic
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4,0K Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    8 Oct 15 22:33 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Sep 10 23:22 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  77M Sep 10 23:22 initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  77M Sep 11 01:32 initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  77M Oct 15 22:12 initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Sep 10 23:22 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 140K Apr  8  2024 memtest86+ia32.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 141K Apr  8  2024 memtest86+ia32.efi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 145K Apr  8  2024 memtest86+x64.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 146K Apr  8  2024 memtest86+x64.efi
-rw-------  1 root root 8,7M Aug  2 16:15 System.map-6.8.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 8,7M Aug 13 12:20 System.map-6.8.0-44-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Sep 10 23:22 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  15M Aug  2 16:39 vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  15M Aug 13 12:22 vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  15M Sep 27 20:47 vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Sep 10 23:22 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic

I still see this as a bug in the grub scripts.
If the bpool is not correctly imported the scripts should either try to do this or - maybe even better - simply exit with a descriptive error.
Also when the grub-probe executable gets an error - see to it it prints out exactly where (on which device) the failing probe was running.
I updated the bug with cannonical to reflect this.
